# Cache Device Context

Tags: c#, windows, gdi+

To draw some text I use

```
Size GetStringSize(LOGFONT logFont, string stringToMeasure)
{
     Font font = FontCache.Default.GetOrCreate(logFont);
     using(var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(Display.HWND))
     {
        return TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, stringToMeasure, font, new Size(1000000, 1000000));
     }
}
```

I can cache the font object without issues. But I am not sure if I can cache the *Graphics* object, or if I can simply use the *Graphics* object of the current display by passing null to *FromHWnd*?

The performance issue is quite real:

```
Line #, Process, Stack Tag, Stack - (Callees of System.Drawing.ni.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr)), Weight (in view) (ms)
7, ,   |  , System.Drawing.ni.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr), 21,334.418715
8, ,   |  ,   |- System.Drawing.ni.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr), 21,304.413686
9, ,   |  ,   |    |- System.Drawing.ni.dll!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.Drawing.FontStyle, Int32 ByRef), 21,264.422130
10, ,   |  ,   |    |    |- GdiPlus.dll!GdipCreateFromHWND, 21,244.429337
11, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |- GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::GetFromHwnd, 21,214.423913
12, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |- GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::GpGraphics, 20,824.349264
13, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |- win32u.dll!ZwUserGetDC, 20,042.878233
14, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd, 19,952.862751
15, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    win32kbase.sys!NtUserGetDC, 19,952.862751
16, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- win32kbase.sys!_GetDCEx, 19,842.849739
17, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- win32kbase.sys!HmgShareLock, 7,384.475206
18, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- win32kbase.sys!HANDLELOCK::vLockHandle, 3,085.609601
19, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx, 2,154.100038
20, ,   |  ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx<itself>, 1,984.037148
```

I spend 21s down there which is quite a lot. This is far away from ns. There are about 4 threads doing this concurrently to speed up drawing.

What can invalidate a cached *Graphics* object? In this case I do not draw anything only measure the text size so it should be pretty easy to cache. The font is specified with a negative Height which means it is declared in pixels.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where Control.CreateGraphics() is the appropriate solution.  Caching is always the wrong strategy when the expense of storing the object is very high and the cost to create it is very low.

Comment: What is the actual issue? The Graphics object is not valid anymore when the DC it's created form is *refreshed* (so, continuosly). You don't ever store it. Also, you should measure the string in the actual context where it will be drawn or otherwise *used*. You can get a Graphics object from the current desktop passing `IntPtr.Zero` to `Graphics.FromHwnd()`. It depends what you're measuring this string for.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually the most expensive thing is creating the Graphics object. I am not trying to optimize at random spots but where ETW Profiling will lead me to. What do you mean with expensive storing? Are you referring to the GDI handle count of 10K per process?

Comment: @Jimi: This is happening on a backend server where some images are rendered. I have therefore only the dimensions of the client screen in pixels but not a real window handle.

Comment: It holds on to a HDC, they are stored on the desktop heap.  Along with other drawing objects, like fonts, it can only store 65535 of those objects that all programs that run on that desktop must share.  It is usually significantly worse in a "backend server" btw, session 0 has a smaller heap.  The cost you measure might well be associated with having to load a bunch of DLLs that are not normally used in a service.  Too much guessing.

Comment: This doesn't explain much. Do you need to draw text on Bitmaps objects? What's the use of the screen as the source of the DC to measure a string? Can't you have a *protoype* Bitmap to create the Graphics context from and use TextRenderer or `Graphics.MeasureString()` to measure it, with DPI and PixelFormat equal to the target DC?

Comment: @HansPassant: The costs are mainly Spinlocks in GDI32 inside the kernel. Not sure what they are all about but since text rendering is multi threaded 
 creating the Graphics objects is pretty expensive. If they have no thread affinity I could use them even from multiple threads? That could in effect lower the GDI resource consumption.

Comment: Hmya, that's what ETW tells you about.  It doesn't tell you what MeasureText() costs.  There's a big difference between 50 nanoseconds and a microsecond, hard to see when you can't see the microsecond.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have added profiling data. It costs 21s which is far away from ns.

Comment: @Jimi: I am interested in when the DC will be refreshed?

Comment: @HansPassant: As profiling shows we this is called far too often. Would I get away with it by caching it for 10s and then let it go?